# Using require to load images in Angular 11 app

Tags: html, angular, image, require

I was trying to load some images in an Angular 11 app in the traditional way by adding `<img src="../xxx/yyy"` into Html but it returned *404 error*. (I'm sure that the path is OK). Afterwards, I tried the require solution but it failed again.
This is the way I'm using require.
Any ideas-solutions?

Typescript

```
declare var require: any;
imgname= require("../../assets/images/Component95_1.png").default;
```

Html

```
<img src={{imgname}}>
```

Comment: static images or coming from API?

Comment: No, they are not coming from an Api

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `assets` directory in `src`. With full path you can get the image. [example](https://scotch.io/courses/build-your-first-angular-website/adding-an-imagelogo-in-angular)

I recommend to set `src` via input directive: `<img [src]="imgname">`

Comment: Did you tried with path like this  ```assets/...``` ?

Comment: It gives me cannot resolve the path..I mean in the case I use require. Without require, that solution again gives me 404